# Connect Crystal Report to multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server, database, crystal-reports, partition

Is there a way to connect a crystal report to multiple databases?

My database (SQL Server) is periodically archived and sometimes, I need to access data from an older "partition"/archive, let's call them DB109 and DB110. I need to produce one report with data from both DB109 and DB110. They have the same structure, same query, etc.

Is there a way to run the report for both DBs without running them separately and ending up with multiple files?

Comment: Change your approach to the "push" model....where you populate a dataset with data and "push" in into the Crystal Report.  Then you can populate the dataset from 1 to N source databases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could probably make two subreports, with one linking to one db and the other linking to the second.  Add a parameter on whether to run the first, second, or both.  And then conditionally display the subreports based on the parameter.

A second option would be to have a linked server in your main database to your archive database, and then write a procedure that pulls from both (perhaps also based on a parameter).  Then use that procedure as your Crystal source.